# How to Replace the generic css style into empty string using C#

Tags: c#, css, replace

When i take a list of items from one list, some **css** styles are added into that. I want to remove / Replace that. 
The following code is used  to replace the style generic. But it is not given the result.

```
flag.Text = flag.Text.Replace("style=[\"'](.*)[\"']", "");
```

But it is not replacing. How to give this. Or shall i use `Contains` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to try using `Regex.Replace` (and using `Multiline` option, just in case) instead of `string.Replace`:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline; 
flag.Text = Regex.Replace(flag.Text, "style=[\"'](.*)[\"']", "", options);
```

What you show above is `Replace` using `string.Replace`. It tries to find exact match of the *static* text instead of text with *pattern*. If you want to replace text with *pattern*, use `Regex.Replace` instead.

Comment: `"<strong><span style=\"text-decoration:underline;\"><span style=\"font-family:'Calibri', 'sans-serif';color:#1f497d;font-size:11pt;\">New business only</span></span></strong><span style=\"font-family:'Calibri', 'sans-serif';color:#1f497d;font-size:11pt;\">-some text will show’</span>"`. This is the style will  passing from server. But i should replace with generic one.

Comment: @PoliDev what is the "Generic one" you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to replace the style by using the string.replace() methode but i think it cant do a regex like replace. I think you need to take a look at [Regex.Replace](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-replace).